# How do I have 2 color versions of the same site in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

How do I create a scenario where a user chooses a side (left or right) and based on their choice a logo would appear in one color vs the opposite choice would be in another color throughout the site?

I basically have 2 sides of the same site and want to be able to have a different color scheme for each. Even though it serves up the same content otherwise.

I've tried looking into global variables and using both javascript and php but I've been getting lost.

Does anyone have a suggestion for a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Add a css class to the header or body which, based on the users selection, updates the page styling.

You have to define the layout_field but this will set the css class.

```
<body <?php body_class( 'layout_field' ? 'left' : 'right ); ?>>
```

Then in your styling you can do something like:

```
body.left {
    .logo {
        color: blue;
    }
}

body.right {
    .logo {
        color: red;
    }
}
```